# Not Getting Same Text while converting the image to text using mathpix, how to search using regex in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Not Getting Same Text while converting the image to text using mathpix, how to search using regex in MySQL database.

**Question Image :-**
[image: Question Image]

Question Image Text:- The population ( P ) of a town decreases at rate proportional to the number by which the population exceeds 1000 , proportionality constant being ( \mathrm{k}>0 ). Find (a) Population at any time t, given initial population of the town being 2500 . (b) If 10 years later the population has fallen to 1900 , find the time when the population will be 1500 . (c) Predict about the population of the town in the long run.

**Searching Image:-**
[image: Searching Image]

Searching Image Text:- The population ( P ) of a town decreases at rate proportional to the number by which the population exceeds ( 1000, ) proportionality constant being ( \mathrm{k}>0 ). Find (a) Population at any time t, given initial population of the town being 2500 . (b) If 10 years later the population has falleñ to 1900 , find the time when the population will be 1500 . (c) Predict about the population of the town in the long run.

If you see both texts are different, how to search this in MySQL, I tried with like and substring text and match but not working with every scenario, is there any percentage matching concept in MySql???

Comment: No, there is no percentage match functionality in mysql. Mysql is a relational database, not a text mining tool. Python or R would be better suited for such problems. Text mining libraries, such as nltk or spacy have advanced comparison features, like cosign similarity. You need to study the different text comparison techniques and decide which one to use based on your requirements.

Comment: thanks for your early reply @Shadow, can I use elastic search for this???

Comment: It seems so: https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch pls note, it took me about 5 seconds to find this article using elastic search text comparison as search expression. You could have done the same...